# When I use static methods in client-side code in GWT, how much code is compiled?

Tags: gwt

I want to use some of Google Guava methods and classes in my client-side GWT code, but I'm concerned about client code size. For example, if I use `Strings.nullToEmpty` method, does the entire `Strings` class get compiled or only the `nullToEmpty` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the GWT compiler compiles only those methods that can be called; since no runtime introspection is available, it can deduce the complete call-graph, and compile only those parts (and optimise it accordingly).

Comment: +1 this is true. Check your SOYC report to see exactly what classes/methods are included in your compiled GWT code, and why they ended up there. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html